# how can I run async await with delay in react-native component?

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

How can run this function with delay for 5 second?

```
export default class Splash extends React.PureComponent  {

constructor() {
    super();
    this._bootstrapAsync();
 }
bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    //await Task.Delay(5);
    //await timeout(5000)
    //await sleep(5000);
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
    this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
  };
```

I tried these:

```
 await Task.Delay(3);
```

And

```
 await timeout(5000);
```

And

```
 await sleep(2000);
```

Comment: `setTimeout`? .

Comment: May be it's wrong. I googled it.

Comment: You put inside the function `setTimeout(function() { // run here the user token }, 5000);` . So `bootstrapAsync = async () => { // setTimeout }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This promise resolves in `ms` milliseconds:

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
```

You use it like `await sleep(5000)` instead of the code that didn't work for you.

Comment: I would check out the documentation on MDN too for Async functions :) 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: And also this article I wrote on the above function :) [Sleeping in JavaScript](https://medium.com/@nino.filiu/sleeping-in-javascript-e00a1ebbde2e)

Comment: Oh, I was referring to the Questioner checking it out not you. Your answer is great :)

Comment: I gave it a few claps! Nice article.